# Json string getting value with link angualr4

Tags: html, angular

I am getting json value like "desc: some text {{here| www.test.com}} sometext {{link| www.anotherlink.com}} some more text"..

I need to show UI side like " some text [here](http://test.com) sometext [link](http://anotherlink.com) some more text"

Comment: Can you post your json response please?

Comment: response will be "{  "desc":"examples of {{here|https://www.google.com/}}. If your {{click|http://gmail.com/}} info."
      },"